# Relative file referencing with SVN on Windows

Tags: windows, svn, symlink

I have a project with a sizable codebase. Associated with that codebase is a large amount of documenation that needs to maintained at the same version as the source code and which also needs to be easily accessible from within the codebase. However when our build machine builds the codebase I do not want the length of our build process extended by having the build machine checking out hundreds of megabytes of development documentation which is not needed for the build.

If this was on Unix I could simply have a 'docs' directory at the peer level of the codebase's 'source' directory. Then individual projects in the source tree could reference documentation in the docs tree using symlinks, and when the build machine does a build it would just check out the source directory and so not waste time checking out the unneeded docs directory.

However using SVN on Windows I don't see any way to set this up in a sensible way at all since SVN doesn't support symbolic links on Windows, even though Windows has them.

The only workaround I've come up with so far is to create batch files in the source tree which use cmd.exe and a relative file reference to open the documentation files in the docs tree. It works, but for some reason I can't quite put my finger on it leaves a nasty taste in the mouth.

Can anyone think of a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

After some research I think I have a solution using the externals property.

Firstly using the svn:external property to reference a directory in the same repository. Set this on trunk/Proj1 to create Proj1/Docs referencing the contents of DocsDir/Proj1Docs

```
../DocsDir/Proj1Docs Docs
```

This creates a disconnected child working copy inside Proj1/Docs which references /DocsDir/Proj1Docs. Proj1/docs must *not* previously exist as part of the outer working copy (which makes sense since that would make it part of two working copies at once). If you edit the contents of Proj1/Docs then executing svn status inside the 'parent' working copy will list the changes to the child working copy, but you have to commit the changes to the child copy separately. Which is not a big deal.

Secondly using the svn:external property to reference to a file in the same repository. Set this on trunk/Proj1 to create Proj1/Readme.txt which references DocsDir/Readme.txt.

```
../DocsDir/Readme.txt Readme.txt
```

In the case of a file reference the directory in which the referenced file is imported must already be part of the owning working copy. In this case no child working copy is created and if you edit the file it is commited seamlessly as part of the owning working copy.

In both cases the build machine can execute

```
svn checkout --ignore-externals <path>
```

to checkout our codebase without all the bulky documentation.

Can anyone see a problem with this strategy?